# Swift WebKit Picture in Picture

Tags: swift, webview, webkit, picture-in-picture

How can you enable Picture-in-Picture on a Swift WebView from WebKit?

At the moment, when you watch a video in a webView and switch to the home screen, you briefly see the picture-in-picture view in the top right on the home screen, but it disappears after a second.

How can you retain it so it doesn't disappear?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you enabled Picture in Picture under BackgroundModes in Xcode.

**TARGETS -> Signing & Capabilities -> Background Mode**

[image]

> If you are trying to embed a youtube video in your webView, PiP won't work. Youtube blocking PiP in iOS webView and Safari.

For youtube videos embedding is better to use the [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) framework.

Comment: Ah, the issue was just with Youtube blocking it the entire time. Thanks